# Forecasting using Python(Pytools) in QlikSense Desktop

Tags: python, qliksense

I am using QlikSense Desktop latest version and trying to run forecasting using Pytools.Prophet.

But it's not showing me the output.  Here is the data and function I have used.

```
PyTools.Prophet([Data_col.autoCalendar.Date],Avg(Shipments),'freq=M'). I am not getting the forecast line.
```

The  Qlik py tools is in C:\Users\user-name\Documents\qlik-py-tools-6.2  folder and I start the file "Qlik-Py-Start.bat".

I start the .bat file and then open the Qliksense Desktop app which is in  C:\Users\user-name\Documents\Qlik\Sense\Apps.

Its just showing this in command prompt:

```
2020-01-13 21:49:45,114 - INFO - Adding to capabilities: Prophet_Multivariate(['a_date', 'b_value', 'c_holidays', 'd_added_regressors', 'e_regressor_args', 'f_other_args'])
2020-01-13 21:49:45,114 - INFO - Adding to capabilities: Prophet_Seasonality_Multivariate(['a_season', 'b_time_series', 'c_holidays', 'd_added_regressors', 'e_regressor_args', 'f_other_args'])
2020-01-13 21:49:45,114 - INFO - Adding to capabilities: sklearn_Calculate_Metrics_Sequence(['a_model_name', 'b_key', 'n_features'])
2020-01-13 21:54:15,378 - INFO - ipv6:[::1]:55612 - Capability 'Prophet' called by user Personal\Me from app C:\Users\user-name\Documents\Qlik\Sense\Apps\forecastv2.qvf
2020-01-13 21:54:15,379 - INFO - ExecuteFunction (functionId: 5, _prophet)
_
```

I have also changed the init file in both the location to: `SSEPlugin=PyTools,localhost:50055;`
one at C:/Users//Documents/Qlik/Sense/ and another at C:/Users/AppData/Local/Programs/Qlik/Sense/Engine. Added the SSE settings to both files.

[image]

Here is the data that I am using:

```
 Quarter    Shipments
1/1/1986    4009
2/1/1986    4123
3/1/1986    4493
4/1/1986    4595
5/1/1986    4245
6/1/1986    4321
7/1/1986    4522
8/1/1986    4806
9/1/1986    4799
10/1/1986   4900
11/1/1986   400
12/1/1986   5000
1/1/1987    3000
2/1/1987    2456
3/1/1987    1234
4/1/1987    3456
5/1/1987    7878
```

`Here is the debug result:`

ProphetForQlik Log: Wed Jan 15 11:03:33 2020

Prophet parameters: {'freq': 'M', 'debug': 'true'}

Instance creation parameters: {}

Make future data frame parameters: {'periods': 0, 'freq': 'M'}

Add seasonality parameters: {}

Fit parameters: {}

REQUEST DATA FRAME: (17, 2) rows x cols

```
      ds           y
   0 1986-01-01  4009.0
   1 1986-02-01  4123.0
   2 1986-03-01  4493.0
   3 1986-04-01  4595.0
   4 1986-05-01  4245.0
    ...
       ds       y
   12 1987-01-01  3000.0
   13 1987-02-01  2456.0
   14 1987-03-01  1234.0
   15 1987-04-01  3456.0
   16 1987-05-01  7878.0
```

INPUT DATA FRAME: (0, 2) rows x cols

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ds, y]
Index: []
...
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ds, y]
Index: []

Forecast cannot be generated as the request contains less than two non-Null rows

When I pass this data:

```
          Quarter   Shipments
1/1/1986    4009
2/1/1986    4123
3/1/1986    4493
4/1/1986    4595
5/1/1986    4245
6/1/1986    4321
7/1/1986    4522
8/1/1986    4806
9/1/1986    4799
10/1/1986   4900
11/1/1986   400
12/1/1986   5000
1/1/1987    3000
2/1/1987    2456
3/1/1987    1234
4/1/1987    3456
5/1/1987    7878
6/1/1987    
7/1/1987    
8/1/1987
```

When I run on this data with future values then Python throws an error.

REQUEST DATA FRAME: (22, 2) rows x cols

```
      ds       y
  0 1986-01-01  4009.0
  1 1986-02-01  4123.0
  2 1986-03-01  4493.0
  3 1986-04-01  4595.0
  4 1986-05-01  4245.0
  ...
       ds   y
 17 1987-06-01 NaN
18 1987-07-01 NaN
19 1987-08-01 NaN
20 1987-09-01 NaN
21 1987-10-01 NaN
```

INPUT DATA FRAME: (17, 2) rows x cols

```
      ds       y
0 1986-01-01  4009.0
1 1986-02-01  4123.0
2 1986-03-01  4493.0
3 1986-04-01  4595.0
4 1986-05-01  4245.0
```

...
           ds       y
    12 1987-01-01  3000.0
    13 1987-02-01  2456.0
    14 1987-03-01  1234.0
    15 1987-04-01  3456.0
    16 1987-05-01  7878.0

2020-01-15 11:59:36,511 - ERROR - Exception iterating responses: object of type  cannot be safely interpreted as an integer.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user-name\Documents\qlik-py-tools-6.3\qlik-py-env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\function_base.py", line 117, in linspace
    num = operator.index(num)
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object c
annot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user-name\Documents\qlik-py-tools-6.3\qlik-py-env\lib\site-packages\grpc_server.py", line 453, in _take_response_from_response_iterator
    return next(response_iterator), True

File "**main**.py", line 342, in _prophet
    forecast = predictor.predict()
  File "C:\Users\user-name\Documents\qlik-py-tools-6.3\qlik-py-env\core_prophet.py", line 272, in predict
    self.model.fit(self.input_df, **self.fit_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user-name\Documents\qlik-py-tools-6.3\qlik-py-env\lib\site-packages\fbprophet\forecaster.py", line 1032, in fit
    self.set_changepoints()

File "C:\Users\user-name\Documents\qlik-py-tools-6.3\qlik-py-env\lib\site-packages\fbprophet\forecaster.py", line 347, in set_changepoints
    np.linspace(0, hist_size - 1, self.n_changepoints + 1)

File "<**array_function** internals>", line 6, in linspace

File "C:\Users\user-name\Documents\qlik-py-tools-6.3\qlik-py-env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\function_base.py", line 121, in linspace
    .format(type(num)))

TypeError: object of type  cannot be safely interpreted as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

The terminal shows that your function is being executed, so the problem is in the data being sent to the function. Try passing `debug=true` in your arguments (in addition to `freq`) and trace through the steps being taken in Python.

```
PyTools.Prophet([Data_col.autoCalendar.Date],Avg(Shipments),'freq=M, debug=True')
```

Based on the data you posted, an obvious problem is that you are missing the future periods. The forecast is generated for a number of future periods which need to be passed from Qlik as a datetime field with a `NULL` value for the measure.

The usage documentation on GitHub goes into the details: https://github.com/nabeel-oz/qlik-py-tools/blob/master/docs/Prophet.md

Update: The debug logs you have added confirm that the input data does not contain any future periods. You can see this under `Make future data frame parameters`. The input dataframe ends up empty in this case and you won't get a forecast. You'll need to generate the future periods in Qlik or in the data source as explained in the usage doc above.

Comment: Updated the result with new data frame.

Comment: This new error that you're getting is due to an incompatibility between the latest version of numpy and fbprophet. This has been addressed in the latest release (v.6.4) of PyTools and the [related issue on GitHub](https://github.com/nabeel-oz/qlik-py-tools/issues/86#issuecomment-575389511).

Comment: Still getting error. Updated the error in https://github.com/nabeel-oz/qlik-py-tools/issues/86